# How to sort data but leaving out a specific record to be the first(should not be affected by the sort) on the returned results in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement that retrieves data and sorts the data by one of the columns, at the moment all the fields are sorting accordingly but I would like to have a specific row to always be the first and not be affected by the sort. Here is what I have done:

```
select distinct 
    colID,  
    colA,
    colB,
    colC      
from
    vw_dATA
where 
    (colID = 1)
order by  
    colB
```

Comment: And? What is the question ?

Comment: How do I Order the the returned except for a specific row since I want it to always be the first?

Comment: "Order the the returned except for a specific row" is not possible in SQL. When you specify `ORDER BY` all rows are sorted.  So you have to think of a way to have the record that you want first to be ordered as first record. (see: the answer already given)

Comment: I got the answer I was looking for. Check the answer by @The Impaler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine multiple sorting criteria with a `CASE` statement. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select distinct colID,  
    colA,
    colB,
    colC,
    my_row_id
  from vw_dATA
  where colID = 1
) x
order by
  case when my_row_id = 1234 then 1 else 2 end, -- first ordering criteria
  colB -- rest of the ordering
```

Comment: I get this error when I run your anwer : ' ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.'

Comment: @Gov-G Fixed. When a `DISTINCT` is used, the query should be placed as a subquery, and the `ORDER BY` clause should be extracted out.